# In Lemma 10.53.5 of Stacks (about commutative Artinian rings), how did they use localisation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, localization, artinian

Link here: [https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00J4#:~:text=A%20ring%20R%20is%20Artinian%20if%20and%20only%20if%20it,localizations%20at%20its%20maximal%20ideals](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00J4#:%7E:text=A%20ring%20R%20is%20Artinian%20if%20and%20only%20if%20it,localizations%20at%20its%20maximal%20ideals)

> **Lemma 10.53.5**. *Any ring with finitely many maximal ideals and locally nilpotent Jacobson radical is the product of its localizations at its maximal ideals. Also, all primes are maximal.*

In Lemma 10.53.5, where did they apply localisation? I see they've used the Chinese Remainder Theorem, using which they've extracted some idempotents $(e_i)_i$.

Consider $e_j \neq e_k$, both not in $\mathfrak m_i$. I suppose we get $\frac{e_j}{1} = \frac{e_j e_k}{e_k} = \frac{0}{e_k} = 0$. So localisation at $\mathfrak m_i$ kills all $e_j \neq e_i$.

How do you show that the subset $R e_i$ gets left alone by this localisation?

Consider $\frac{x e_i}{1} = \frac{0 e_i}{1}$. By the definition of localisation, we get that $t(x e_i) = 0$ for some $t \not \in \mathfrak{m}_i$. I'd like to somehow cancel the $t$ to get $x e_i = 0$, but I'm not sure how to justify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the isomorphism $R\cong \prod_i Re_i$ as the starting point. The maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}_i$ on the left corresponds to the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{M}_i=Re_1\times\cdots\times Re_{i-1}\times \mathfrak{m}_ie_i\times Re_{i+1}\times\cdots\times Re_n$ on the right. So $R_{\mathfrak{m}_i}\cong\left(\prod_j Re_j\right)_{\mathfrak{M}_i}$. But now I claim that $\left(\prod_j Re_j\right)_{\mathfrak{M}_i}\cong Re_i$. Indeed, we have a natural map $\phi:Re_i\to \left(\prod_j Re_j\right)_{\mathfrak{M}_i}$. If an element $re_i$ is mapped to $0$ then by definition of localisation there exists $se_i\in Re_i\setminus \mathfrak{m}_ie_i$ such that $re_ise_i=0$. But $\mathfrak{m}_ie_i$ is the unique maximal ideal of $Re_i$, so $se_i$ is a unit, and hence $re_i=0$. Hence the map is injective.

To see surjectivity, take an arbitrary element $x/y\in\left(\prod_j Re_j\right)_{\mathfrak{M}_i}$. Let $\tilde{e}_i$ be the element of $\prod_j Re_j$ with $(\tilde{e}_i)_j=0$ if $j\neq 0$ and $(\tilde{e}_i)_i=e_i$. Then $\tilde{e}_i\notin\mathfrak{M}_i$, so $x/y=(x\tilde{e}_i)/(y\tilde{e}_i)=\phi(x_ie_i)/\phi(y_ie_i)$. But note that $y_ie_i\notin\mathfrak{m}_ie_i$ by definition, so $y_ie_i$ is a unit of $Re_i$, and hence $x/y=\phi((xe_i)(ye_i)^{-1})$. Hence $\phi$ is also surjective.

Therefore, we obtain $R_{\mathfrak{m}_i}\cong Re_i$ and conclude.